# Can I use NetworkExtension to sniff HTTPS traffics with SSL Pinning?

Tags: ios, networkextension

Since I cannot use Charles to sniff HTTPS traffics of apps that use SSL Pinning I'm wondering whether it is possible to do that using [NetworkExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension) on iOS devices.

Comment: If you want to check your apps traffic you could always disable pinning in debug.

Comment: @Losiowaty I’m not talking about my own apps.